# CakePHP email change the word that comes after via

Tags: php, email, cakephp

I am sending emails using CakePHP's built in email functionality

Everytime i'm sending email, i get this one

[image]

Here is my code:

```
    $email = new CakeEmail();
    foreach($userReceiverEmail as $key => $value){
        $email->reset();
        $email->from(array($userSenderEmail=>$userSender));
        $email->replyTo($userSenderEmail);
        $email->to($value);
        $email->emailFormat('html');
        $email->subject($subject);
        if(@$email->send($msg)){
            $mailSentCounter++;
        }
    }
```

How can I change the `via host.mysite.com` into something like `via admin.host.com`?

Your help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: try this $email = new CakeEmail();
    foreach($userReceiverEmail as $key => $value){
        $email->reset();
        $email->from(array($userSenderEmail=>$userSender));
        $email->config('gmail' or 'smtp' or . base on what server you use);
        $email->emailFormat('html');
        $email->replyTo($userSenderEmail);
        $email->to($value);
        $email->subject($subject);
        if(@$email->send($msg)){
            $mailSentCounter++;
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

Just customise your email template.

Take a look at the documentation: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html#sending-templated-emails